# Склеивается путь прикладываемого файла при отладке веб приложения. Почему, если в конфиге указан правильно?

Tags: javascript, samba, vaadin

> Tue Jan 22 16:42:23 GMT+300 2019
>   com.vaadin.client.communication.AtmospherePushConnection
>
> {"686":{"text":"Акт сверки сформирован, запускается Outlook"}},
>   "types":{"620":"0","686":"7","693":"37"},  "rpc" :
>   [["693","com.vaadin.shared.extension.javascriptmanager.ExecuteJavaScriptRpc","executeJavaScript",["var
>   msApp = new ActiveXObject(\"Outlook.Application\"); var objNS =
>   msApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI'); var theMailItem = msApp.CreateItem(0);
>   theMailItem.to = ('test@gmail.com'); theMailItem.Subject = ('subj');
>   theMailItem.Body = ('body');
>   theMailItem.Attachments.Add(\"\Ms-bssfixsrv001\reports_for_ARFIX_actsАкт_сверки_DQ100_11.01.2019_22.01.20197527584528452576062.xlsx\");
>   theMailItem.display(); "]]], "meta" : {"async":true}, "resources" :
>   {}, "typeMappings"

"_ARFIX_actsАкт_сверки_DQ" - тут между словами acts и Акт_сверки должен быть "/"

Comment: Почему "/", если везде используется "\"?

Comment: Суть была в кодировке UTF8